# Must I cleanup my child UIViewControllers when my container UIViewController is dealloc-ed or unloaded?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a simple container `UIViewController` with a single child `UIViewController`.

Do I need to send the child `willMoveToParentViewController:` and `removeFromParentViewController` in my container `UIViewController`'s `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` methods?

I'm using `ARC`

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but I had the same problem. I tested with NSLog and the dealloc method did not get called on child controllers.

In my case, I have a parent controller having a child controller, but this parent is also a child to another super parent controller.

So, my solution is to implement willMoveToParentViewController and remove the child there.

```
- (void) willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent;
{
    if (parent == nil) {
        NSLog(@"removing my self");
        [_childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [_childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        [_childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        _childViewController = nil;
    }
}
```

But, in my case, I called this method because this parent is a child of another parent controller.

```
// removing the parent from super parent controller
[_parentViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[_parentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
[_parentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
_parentViewController = nil;
```

I don't know about your case though, but hopefully this will help others who might have the same problem with me.